# Multiple searches in same column MySQL Sequelize,

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I am making a search in a database which have a table productDetails.
I want a query something like this in sequelize,
SELECT * FROM `productDetails` WHERE `title` LIKE '%search1%' OR `title` LIKE '%search2%'

currently using

```
const pd= await ProductDetail.findAll({
where: {
  [Op.or]: {
    title: { [Op.like]: `%search1%` },
    title: { [Op.like]: `%search2%` },
  },
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just indicate all conditions as an array as a value of `Op.or` like this:

```js
where: {
  [Op.or]: [
   { title: { [Op.like]: `%search1%` } },
   { title: { [Op.like]: `%search2%` } },
  ],
},
```

See examples [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#operators)